# npm workspaces "WARN: some-package-name in filter set, but no workspace folder present"

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a repo with many npm packages inside, using [npm workspaces](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/workspaces)

The top-level `package.json` contains the line:

```
  "workspaces": [
    "*"
  ]
```

When I run `npm i -ws` or other npm commands, I receive the warning:

```
WARN: some-package-name in filter set, but no workspace folder present
```

I'm not quite sure what the message means - I *think* the 'filter set' is the `-w` option, but the workspace folder `some-package-name` definitely exists.

One note is that the `some-package-name/package.json` contains an org prefix, eg:

```
"name": "@mycompany/some-package-name",
```

So maybe that's the cause. I can't rename the folder from `some-package-name` to `@mycompany/some-package-name` though as I'm concerned a directory starting with `@` may break things.

**What does the warning mean and how can I resolve it?**

Comment: running the command twice worked for me somehow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into the same problem, using the name configured in the workspace's package instead of the folder name fixed the issue for me, even with an `@`.

`npm install --workspace=@mycompany/some-package-name`

Comment: I think that was the cause of my problem too.

Essentially - and what I didn't understand - was that `-ws` stands for **all workspaces**. `-w` means a single workspace.

Answer (score 3):

I have run into the same problem recently with my monorepo: the reason was that the project's name (without the scope) in `package.json` did not match the name of the directory (subproject) it was stored within.

If the subprojects of the monorepo are stored within a `packages` directory in the project root and the root `package.json` contains

```json
"workspaces": [
    "packages/*"
]
```

then **npm** expects a subproject named `@<scope>/project-name` to be in the directory `packages/project-name`.

Comment: I seem to be getting the same error regardless of whether I make an @scope/module_name directory or just a module_name directory
Edit: Turns out if you were faking workspaces by putting a 'node_modules' directory in the path, npm workspaces does not like it, and you have to remove that

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue using a `file:` dependency as "recommended by npm" (read below).

Actually many articles say that npm recommends to use `file:` to reference a dependency between two workspace packages (and then often they use the asterisk anyway) but honestly I did not found that hint in npm docs, but it works! ... at least it worked for me, using the following

#### Explicitly list the workspaces

So instead of using an asterisk I have, for example

```json
  "workspaces": [
    "packages/models",
    "packages/database",
    "webapp"
  ]
```

#### I also have a scoped package name

for instance

```json
  "name": "@project/models",
  "private": "true"
```

#### I am using "file:" dependencies

Instead of

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "@project/models": "*"
  }
```

I use `file:WORKSPACE_PATH`

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "@project/models": "file:packages/models"
  }
```

Comment: You say "as recommended by npm"; do you have a link to any documentation?

Comment: @DaveStewart it is quoted and immediately below I wrote that I found no reference to that in official npm docs but I found few articles googling that mentioned it, that is why I am sharing what I found out. I hope that my message is more clear now.

Comment: OK, I just got this working, but I had to use a relative path from the workspace package file: `"@tools/web-tools": "file:../../tools/web-tools"`... and – of course – run `npm install` from the root again.

Comment: I believe using 'file:' is a legacy way to do monorepo.

Comment: Indeed. Each workspaces should have a symlink in the root node_modules that the other workspaces can use to declare proper dependencies, so that you don't have to use file dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I have a slightly different answer.

I'm creating a `package.json` programatically, using `Fs.writeFileSync('./path/to/package.json')`.

I run `npm install -w=workspace foo bar` immediately after, but it seems that this fails *sometimes*; NPM somehow hasn't picked up on the file, as if I run the same command twice, the second one always works.

Adding a small delay using `setTimeout()` also works, though I feel a bit dirty having had to do this; I don't know if this is an issue with Node or my lack of knowledge around Node's process lifecycle.

Anyway, in this case – and in lieu of better solution – it works.

Comment: `fs.writeFileSync()` should block until complete. However some operating systems acknowledge writes before they've actually happened.